# Custom doclet in a maven project - invalid flag

Tags: java, maven, javadoc, doclet

I am trying to generate javadoc on my maven project. I am using Java 1.8, and have written a small doclet project. The pom on my project has -

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.9.1</version>
       <configuration>
          <aggregate>true</aggregate>
          <doclet>org.mydoclet.MyDoclet</doclet>
          <docletArtifact>
            <groupId>mydoclet</groupId>
            <artifactId>mydoclet</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
          </docletArtifact>
          <additionalOptions>
            <additionalOption>-views</additionalOption>
          </additionalOptions>
          <useStandardDocletOptions>false</useStandardDocletOptions>
          <destDir>docs</destDir>
            </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
 </build>
```

I try to run javadoc:aggregate on this. I get an error

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.9.1:aggregate (default-cli) on project <>: An error has occurred in JavaDocs report generation:
[ERROR] Exit code: 1 - javadoc: error - invalid flag: -Xdoclint:none
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Command line was: <javahome/bin>/javadoc @options @packages
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

I have been following the Maven page on writing doclets - https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/examples/alternate-doclet.html#